# Download workflow for updating files and deleting old version

Tags: java, android

I wish my android app to check a server for the latest version of a file (eg map123.map)
If this version is newer than the version in internal storage (map122.map) then download new file to internal storage (not scoped storage). After download is complete I wish to delete old file (map122) . Considerations , file is large 500mb, Download should only occur when WiFi connectivity exists. I'm also concerned about what occurs in the time the new file is being downloaded as it may take 30s to 1 min.

Is there a workflow/best practice for such operations or libraries built to handle such operations ?

Comment: Just do it like you described. What could happen during download that you are afraid of? Why would you need a library to just download a new file and dele an old one?

Comment: @blackapps well I can't use download manager for internal storage, and as the file is 500mb I get memory errors. Just looking for best practice